# Mysql no me muestra todos los registros usando HTML Y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una tabla de calificaciones que va a administrar un profesor.
La tabla que se muestra en la página web contiene `Nombre`, `tareas`, `exámenes`, `promedio`.

Si hay una tarea nueva presiono un botón y este botón genera un nuevo espacio en la tabla de la página web para registrar otra tarea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que al presionar el botón (las veces que yo quiera) se generan esos espacios, pero si quiero ingresar un nuevo alumno presionando otro botón (para ingresar alumno) ya después de que yo presione el botón de agregar nuevas tareas, no se crea un nuevo espacio para alumno.

Pero si presiono el botón de crear alumno, sí se crean nuevos espacios en la tabla (los que quiera), y si presiono el botón de agregar nueva tarea, aunque tenga "n" espacios de alumno, me los quita y deja solo un registro y agrega los espacios de la tarea.

Tanto tareas como el nombre de los alumnos se almacenan en MySQL correctamente, el problema es al traerlo a la página web, no se muestran los espacios del nombre de los alumnos.

No sé si me expliqué bien. Igual anexare unas fotos para ver si me pueden comprender.

Nota: Al presionar el botón de agregar nueva tarea, lo agrego en el campo tareas de la tabla `calificaciones` en un `array(arreglo)`, y para extraerlos después uso `json_decode()`.

Esas tareas podrán ser editas mediante un `href` en cada "T" para que sean dirigidas a una función para editar en la tabla con `$sql`.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, espero me de a entender... Es como una página web dinámica de calificaciones de los alumnos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comparto el código PHP de la página de administración:

```
    <?php 
        require_once('functions/initialize.php');


    if(!empty($_GET)){
      $res = $_GET['res'];
      $subject_tareas1 = find_all_tareas();
            $conttareas = mysqli_num_rows($subject_tareas1);
      if ($res==1) {
         $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        if (!validate_campo($nombre)) {
          insert_alumno($nombre,$conttareas); 
        }else{
        echo  "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> 

        alert('Necesita registrar un nombre'); 
        </script>";
        }
      }else if($res==2){

        $subject_set = find_all_subjects();
       $result = mysqli_num_rows($subject_set);

        insert_tarea();
        if ($result != 0) {
         $alumnos = find_all_subjects();
         $noalumnos = mysqli_num_rows($alumnos);
          $datos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($alumnos);

          $id = $datos['id'];
          if ($datos['tareas'] == "") {

            insert_tareas_vacias($conttareas,$noalumnos);
          }else{
            $tareas = $datos['tareas'];
            agregar_tarea_vacia($conttareas,$noalumnos);
          }

          //si es diferente de 0 voy a agregar el array a la tabla de calificaciones en la columna tareas 
          //con la cantidad de tareas que hay en la tabla tareas pero con atributos vacios
        }
      }else if($res==3){
        delete_tareas();
      }else if($res==4){
        delete_alumnos();
      }


    }



?>

<?php

  $subject_set = find_all_subjects();
  $subject_set2 = find_all_subjects();
  $subject_tareas1 = find_all_tareas();
  $conttareas = mysqli_num_rows($subject_tareas1);

  $result = mysqli_num_rows($subject_set);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilo.css">
    <title>Maestro</title>
</head>
<body>

        <table border="1" width="90%" align="left" > 
 <tr> 
    <th bgcolor="#E9EAEA">NO.</th>
    <th>NOMBRE DEL</th> 
    <th>TAREAS</th>
    <th>EXAMENES</th>
    <th>PROMEDIO</th>


 </tr> 

    <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th align="center">ALUMNO</th>
    <td><table  border="1" width="100%"> 
       <tr> 



        <?php $hw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set2);  //$arraytar = $hw['tareas'];?>


          <?php if ($conttareas != 0) {   ?>

          <?php for ($i=1; $i <= $conttareas ; $i++) {
            $tareas = "T" . $i;
           ?>
            <!--<th align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com"><?php echo $hw[1]; ?></a></th> -->
            <th align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com"><?php echo $tareas?></a></th>


         <?php } ?>

       <?php }else{  ?>
        <th align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">.</a></th>
      <?php } ?>



       </tr> 

        </table></td>

        <td><table  border="1" width="100%"> 
       <tr> 
            <th align="center">EX1</th> 
            <th align="center">EX2</th> 
            <th align="center">EX3</th>
       </tr> 

        </table></td>
        <td bgcolor="#E9EAEA"><table bgcolor="#E9EAEA"  width="100%"> 
       <tr> 
            <th align="center">GENERAL</th> 

       </tr> 

        </table></td>



        <?php for ($i=1; $i <=$result ; $i++) { ?>

        <?php $subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set);  ?>

      <tr>  
      <td align="center"><?php echo $i ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $subject['nombre'] ?></td>   
      <?php var_dump($subject) ?>  
      <!--calificaciones de cada alumno-->
      <td><table  border="1" width="100%"> 
       <tr> 



        <?php $hw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set2);  //$arraytar = $hw['tareas'];?>


          <?php if ($conttareas != 0) {   ?>

          <?php for ($i=1; $i <= $conttareas ; $i++) {
            $tareas = "T" . $i;
           ?>
            <!--<th align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com"><?php echo $hw[1]; ?></a></th> -->
            <td align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com"><?php echo $tareas?></a></td>


         <?php } ?>

       <?php }else{  ?>
        <td align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">.</a></td>
      <?php } ?>



       </tr> 

        </table></td>
      </tr>



    <?php } ?>
        </tr>




</table>

    </br>
  <form action="index.php?res=2"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
        <dt>nueva tarea <input type="submit" value="Agregar" /></dt>


      </dl>

      <div id="operations">
      </div>

    </form>

    <form action="index.php?res=3" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
        <dt>Borrar<input type="submit" value="Borrar Todas" /></dt>


      </dl>

      <div id="operations">
      </div>

    </form>

  <form action="index.php?res=1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
      </br></br></br> </br> </br></br></br>
    </br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
      </br></br></br></br></br></br></br>

        <dt>Nombre Completo <input type="text" name="nombre" value="" /></dt>

      </dl>

      <div id="operations">
        <input type="submit" value="Agregar" />
      </div>

    </form>
  </br></br></br>

<form action="index.php?res=4" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <dl>
      </br></br>

        <dt>Borrar Alumnos<input type="submit" value="Borrar" /></dt>

      </dl>

      <div id="operations">

      </div>

    </form>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad. Si nos facilitas código PHP y HTML para ver cómo estás haciendo el trabajo podremos ayudarte a encontrar el error.

Comment: Hola gracias por comentar, puse un pequeño fragmento que es donde extraigo el nombre de el myslqi_fetch_assoc mediante un For y lo coloco en la columna de nombre. ¿Como podria colocar todo el codigo completo?. Es que estoy manejando el archivo index.php y otro que es donde tengo las funciones de los querys

Comment: ¿De dónde obtienes `$result` para el bucle `for`? ¿Por qué no has usado un `while` comparando cada resultado obtenido con `mysqli_fetch_assoc`? Por el código mostrado muestras datos en celdas de una tabla y a su vez en su interior creas otra tabla más. ¿Qué muestras ahí? Puedes copiar y pegar todo el código completo en la pregunta, pero te recomiendo que uses el mínimo código posible para que podamos reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Pásate por [cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para tener una orientación de lo que necesitamos para poder reproducir tu problema y así poder ayudarte mejor. A veces un exceso de código nos satura y nos desvía del problema real, procura compartirnos el mínimo necesario para que se produzca tu problema y podamos localizar el error.

Comment: Veo muchas llamadas (probablemente innecesarias o redundantes) a funciones como `find_all_subjects()` que no aparece en el código. También llamadas a `delete_alumnos()` y otras funciones sin parámetros que se hacen difícil depurar, no te recomiendo hacer uso en ellas de variables súper globales como `$_GET` o `$_POST`. Luego haces comprobaciones como `!empty($_GET)` y accedes a `$res = $_GET['res']` (que puede no estar definido). Haces `$hw = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subject_set2)` explícitos en dos lugares del código en vez de en un bucle, etc.

Comment: Por el nombre de variable no se puede deducir correctamente su contenido. ¿Habría alguna manera de que me enviaras un volcado de la tabla y el resto del código para poder ejecutar en local tu aplicación?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rgTCS4vSmADCJOGA5aWxQvN11_vDpE4X?usp=sharing

Ahi subi el proyecto completo
y los datos de la base de datos y las tablas
adicional... estoy usando WAMPSERVER

Gracias por tomarte la molestia de ayudarme, en serio que estoy atascado en eso.

Comment: Gracias, ya tengo los archivos (y `phpcs` se ha vuelto loco al pasarlo por tu código). Sólo queda una cosa: el esquema de la base de datos y algunos datos de ejemplo. Si usas phpmyadmin puedes darle a "Exportar" y elegir sólo estructura (esquema) o estructura y datos.

Comment: Listo, ahi subí el archivo sql.

Comment: He solicitado enviar los comentarios a una sala de chat. No estoy seguro si tendrás reputación suficiente para usar el chat, pero tu código necesita demasiadas reformas para hablarlo por medio de comentarios.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93625/discussion-on-question-by-alejandro-cabrera-mysql-no-me-muestra-todos-los-regist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo dos modificaciones a tu código se puede conseguir que aparezca el listado de todos los alumnos.

El primer cambio ha sido hacer una única consulta de alumnos (y no repetirla dos veces) y almacenar en ella todos los registros en la variable:

```
<?php
// Obtenemos una única vez los registros de la tabla "calificacion"
$calificacion = find_all_subjects();
// Almacenamos todos los registros en $calificacion
$subject_set = mysqli_fetch_all($calificacion, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// Liberamos los recursos asociados a la consulta
mysqli_free_result($calificacion);
// No repetimos la misma consulta, copiamos los datos (en realidad, no hace ni falta)
$subject_set2 = $subject_set;
```

El segundo cambio es sustituir los bucles `for` por `foreach` para iterar cada alumno:

```
<?php foreach($subject_set as $i => $subject) { ?>      
<tr>  
<td align="center"><?= $i ?></td>
<td><?= htmlspecialchars($subject['nombre']) ?></td>
```

Adicionalmente, he corregido el bucle de las tareas para que reflejen lo que hay realmente en cada registro del alumno:

```
<?php $tareas = json_decode($subject['tareas']);
if (count($tareas) > 0) {
  foreach ($tareas as $tarea) { ?>
    <td align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">
      <?= htmlspecialchars($tarea) ?>
    </a></td>
  <?php } ?>
<?php } else {  ?>
  <td align="center"><a href="http://www.google.com">.</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

He dejado las modificaciones en este repositorio de github: https://github.com/ojgarciab/263335-maestro

Comment: Oscar, muchas gracias la verdad.
Ya entendi lo que corregiste, parte del problema era tambien que no estaba utilizando un foreach o un while recorriendo el mysqli_fetch_assoc en vez del for que tenia.

Estaba super atascado, me fuiste de mucha ayuda. Entonces ya funciona como lo tenia en mente.
No se de que otra manera agradecerte. 
Como soy nuevo en Stack Overflow, hay alguna manera de darte puntos o algo asi?
Si alguna vez necesita ayuda con algo, con gusto estaré dispuesto a ayudarle.
Aunque veo dificil que tenga un problema con el conocimiento que usted tiene.

Comment: Puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta, con eso será suficiente :)

Comment: Hola @AlejandroCabrera cuando quieras te comento los cambios adicionales que te dije para mejorar tu aplicación.

Comment: Con lo que me corregiste la vez pasada, hice los cambios. El proyecto ya lo entregue en la universidad. Te paso los archivos para que vea como quedo.
De nuevo, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

El profesor ni si quiera le dió por revisar el codigo, y me puso 8/10 por algunos detalles que ni bien especifico.
Por ejemplo en la zona de lista, en agregar nueva fecha me dijo que hubiera estado bueno que no dejara agregar un nuevo dia si ya está agregada la fecha del dia actual.

Cosas de profesores. :P

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1rgTCS4vSmADCJOGA5aWxQvN11_vDpE4X?usp=sharing